# how many conjugacy classes does $D_n$ have if n is even?

Tags: group-theory

From class I remember there are $\frac{n}{2}+3$ of them and a geometric explanation was used as to why there are this many:

[image]

However, material in this question suggests there are $\frac{n}{2}+2$:

[Conjugacy classes of D2n?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/371630/conjugacy-classes-of-d2n)

Why the discrepancy?

Comment: You have to state the geometric explanation, so that we can help you.

Comment: I just posted it

Answer (score 2):

In the other answer also, there seem to be $\frac n2 + 3$ conjugacy classes.

The conjugacy classes in the even case are :$$\{1\}, \{\rho^{\frac n2}\},\{r,r\rho^2,r\rho^4,...,r\rho^{n-2}\},\{r\rho,r\rho^3,...,r\rho^{n-1}\}$$ and $\{\rho^i,\rho^{-i}\}$ for $1 \leq i \leq \frac{n-2}2$. Hence, the answer is $\frac {n-2}{2} + 4 = \frac n2 + 3$.